# "Connection Refused" error when trying to create a new contact

Tags: 4.5

I'm running Civi 4.5.2 on Drupal 7. When I try to create a new organisation, I get a "Connection refused error" with this backtrace. Any ideas what is wrong?

```
backTrace
#0 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(191): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(PEAR_Error))
#2 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(PEAR_Error))
#3 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(566): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("Connection refused", 111, 16, (Array:2), NULL)
#4 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Net/Socket.php(156): PEAR->raiseError("Connection refused", 111)
#5 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTTP/Request.php(737): Net_Socket->connect("maps.googleapis.com", 80, NULL, NULL, NULL)
#6 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Geocode/Google.php(128): HTTP_Request->sendRequest()
#7 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Address.php(394): CRM_Utils_Geocode_Google::format((Array:22))
#8 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Address.php(151): CRM_Core_BAO_Address::fixAddress((Array:22))
#9 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Address.php(128): CRM_Core_BAO_Address::add((Array:22), TRUE)
#10 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Location.php(71): CRM_Core_BAO_Address::create((Array:36), TRUE, NULL)
#11 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php(358): CRM_Core_BAO_Location::create((Array:36), TRUE)
#12 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Contact.php(975): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::create((Array:36), TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
#13 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(328): CRM_Contact_Form_Contact->postProcess()
#14 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(158): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#15 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(129): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->realPerform(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Contact), "upload")
#16 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Contact), "upload")
#17 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Contact), "upload")
#18 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(356): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("upload")
#19 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(117): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#20 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(304): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Contact_Form_Contact", "New Contact", (Array:1))
#21 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(75): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#22 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#23 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(457): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#24 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("contact", "add")
#25 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/includes/menu.inc(517): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#26 /srv/domain.tld/public/htdocs/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#27 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the automatic address geocoding (finding the latitude and longitude using google maps api)

It's probably that your server has a firewall that restrict it to connect to other websites. You should disable the geocoding feature or let the server connect to google maps api server

You'll have a few other features that require the server to connect to external sites (eg. most of the payment processors), it's probably worthwhile opening up more the security, or at least keep in mind when you have a problem that it might be the issue

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I had allowed my server to make connections out to maps.googleapis.com but I think they may have changed IP address recently.